# Saving jpeg image with C#

Tags: c#, image, jpeg

I have a code:

```
Image image1 = Image.FromFile(sOriginalImageFileName, true);
....
image1.Save(sNewFileName, image1.RawFormat);
```

It works good for png's. But opening the new jpeg files with Photoshop, I get

> "Could not complete your request because the file specifies an
>   unsupported JPEG precision"

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`ImageFormat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) enum

```
image1.Save(sNewFileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: You may also want to add the line 
image1.Dispose();
It may not release the file handle unless you do so.  I believe this is a bug and not by design.